# Scala way of filling a template?

Tags: xml, templates, scala

In Ruby I could have this:

```
string=<<EOTEMPLATE
<root>
  <hello>
     <to>%s</to>
     <message>welcome mr %s</message>
  </hello>
  ...
</root>
EOTEMPLATE
```

And when I want to "render" the template, I would do this:

```
rendered = string % ["me@mail.com","Anderson"]
```

And it would fill the template with the values passed in the array. Is there a way to do this in Scala, other than using Java's `String.format`? If I write this in Scala:

```
val myStr = <root>
<hello>
<to>{address}</to>
<message>{message}</message>
</hello>
</root>
```

the resulting XML would already be "filled". Is there a way I could "templatize" the XML?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using a function and Scala's XML:

```
 val tmpl = {(address: String, message: String) =>
  <root>
    <hello>
      <to>{address}</to>
      <message>{message}</message>
    </hello>
  </root>
  }
```

and:

```
tmpl("me@mail.com","Anderson")
```

Some sugar:

```
def tmpl(f: Product => Elem) = new {
   def %(args: Product) = f(args)
}

val t = tmpl{case (address, message) => 
  <root>
    <hello>
      <to>{address}</to>
      <message>{message}</message>
    </hello>
  </root>
}

t % ("me@mail.com","Anderson")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a function for that:

```
val t = (s:String) => <someXML>{s}</someXML>
```

As opposed to format strings, this will give you the benefits of static typing. For example:

```
val ageXml = (age:Int) => <age>{age}</age>
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is great for XML, but for other syntaxes I like Johannes Rudolph's [scala-enhanced-strings](https://github.com/jrudolph/scala-enhanced-strings) plugin.